# Color getAlpha() not working as intended

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I was making a program where I load an image and after that I do something with opaque pixels. Transparent pixels showed up as black pixels, but after some time I found the cause:

```
                                Color c = new Color (input.getRGB(x, y));
    Works->                      if ((input.getRGB(x, y) & 0xFF000000) != 0x00000000) {  do_smth();}
    Returns true at all times->  if (c.getAlpha() != 0) { do_smth(); }
```

So why it does not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`Color`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) constructor does only preserve Alpha values when invoked via [`new Color(rgba, true)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#Color%28int,%20boolean%29). You're missing the `true`, here.

The boolean parameter is described as follows:

> hasalpha - true if the alpha bits are valid; false otherwise